# How do I draw equally sized lines equal distance from each other?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I'm trying to replicate [Matrix.org](https://matrix.org)'s landing page image's [lines](https://matrix.org/images/hero-spiro.svg). How could I do it with reasonable efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Draw two lines, the one at the end and the one at the beginning.

Use the Interpolate extension (Extensions > Create from Path > Interpolate) or the Interpolate Path effect (Path > Path effects > + > Interpolate) to create the intermediate steps.